# Extracting entries from a specific month in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, extract

I'm trying to calculate total revenues from each customer purchase in March from a table called `orders`, where `order_date` is in format of `datetime` (e.g. 2019-03-04). However, I'm unsuccessful to obtain the results with either of the following options:

```
WITH cte_orders AS
(
    SELECT
        cust_id,
        SUM(order_quantity * order_cost) AS revenue
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE 
        DATEPART('month', order_date) = 3
    GROUP BY 
        cust_id
)
SELECT cust_id, revenue 
FROM cte_orders;
```

also

```
WHERE EXTRACT(month from order_date) = '03'
```

or

```
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 03
```

doesn't work either. What's wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: are you sure order_date is being seen as a datetime object? try casting it in the line fore to see if that was the issue. Just a thought as syntax and logic seems correct to me.

Comment: what rdbms do you use?

Comment: @snr PostgreSQL

Comment: can you provide a [mre], so that we can better ujnderstand the problem

Comment: @nbk yes, but its easier that i provide you a link to this particular problem with the exact data and expected output visible: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding-question?id=9782&python= 
-> you can copy paste my code to see the error

Comment: It may be easier for **you** to provide that link. But I have to create an account to use it; an account I do not want. Provide the [mre] here or create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).  Keep in mind the harder it is for the community the less likely you are to get and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the input, finally figured out the right way to do this:

```
WITH cte_orders AS
(
    SELECT 
        cust_id,
        SUM(order_quantity * order_cost) AS revenue,
    FROM 
        orders
    WHERE
        EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM order_date :: TIMESTAMP) = 3
    GROUP BY
        cust_id
)

SELECT cust_id, revenue 
FROM cte_orders;
```

with this it converted the date to timestamp and extracted March as required.

Comment: I was able to get the code running with `date_part` and without casting the `order_date` to a TIMESTAMP or DATE. `WHERE date_part('MONTH', order_date) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

What about `date_part`?

```
WITH cte_orders AS
(select cust_id
    , SUM(order_quantity * order_cost) as revenue
from orders
WHERE date_part('month',TIMESTAMP order_date) = 3
group by cust_id)

select cust_id, revenue from cte_orders;
```

Comment: still nothing, i checked the order_date is really shown as datetime, and im doing this on stratascratch platform as an exercise, for some reason neither date_part() nor month() functions are 'recognized' in the code box. I believe the task wants me to use extract() function, but WHERE EXTRACT(month from order_date) = '03' still doesnt work.

Comment: `WHERE date_part('MONTH', order_date) = 3` works. I think the syntax above is off.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider putting the WHERE clause outside of the CTE?

```
WITH cte_orders AS
(
    SELECT
        cust_id,
        SUM(order_quantity * order_cost) AS revenue
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE 
        DATEPART('month', order_date) = 3
    GROUP BY 
        cust_id
)
SELECT cust_id, revenue 
FROM cte_orders
WHERE MONTH(order_date) = 03;
```

Also, it would be helpful if you let us know what (if any) results you are getting. Are you getting an error message or is it just not returning the expected values/row count?

Comment: Should be `date_part` because it's postgres